# openssl_seal in PHP generates "503 Service Unavailable" page

Tags: php, http-status-code-503, php-openssl

So, a library from a payment processor started to show a 503 page out of the blue. I narrowed the problem to a `openssl_seal` call. To simplify things I adapted and ran the example from the `openssl_seal` manual page and it also throws a 503 page on this server, while working fine on another. This is the code:

```
<?php
  $certPath='public.cer';

  $data = "This is top secret.";
  $cert = file_get_contents($certPath);

  $pk1 = openssl_get_publickey($cert);
  $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);

  $publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_public("file://{$certPath}");
  $publicKeys = array($publicKey);

  openssl_seal($data, $sealed, $ekeys, $publicKeys); // throws a 503 on one server, works fine on another

  openssl_free_key($pk1);
  echo base64_encode($sealed);
?>
```

The PHP version is 5.6.40 on both servers.

The fact that it works on a server and not on the other, leads me to believe that it's something that I should take up with the hosting company, but I'm so outside my field of expertise that I don't know where to look for problems or what to ask for. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. It was fixed through modifications in .htaccess file.
Try to add to .htaccess file this code:

```
<IfModule lsapi_module><FilesMatch "\.(php|php4|php5|php7|phtml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-alt-php55___lsphp
  </FilesMatch></IfModule>
```